# Query on JOINS and Distinct

Tags: join, left-join, distinct

Following are not exactly the same tables, but I'm just simulating the table structure.

```
Table - Columns
Company - comp_id (primary), parent_id;
Department - comp_id, emp_id, dept_id(primary);

parent_id- one to many - comp_id;

comp_id - one to many - dept_id;

dept_id - one to many - emp_id;


requirement is to retrieve parent_id, count(dept_id), count(emp_id) group by parent_id
```

I tried with the following query, but it demands using DISTINCT which might hamper performance.

```
SELECT c.parent_id, 
COUNT(DISTINCT c.comp_id), 
COUNT(d.emp_id) 
FROM company c 
LEFT JOIN department d ON c.comp_id = d.comp_id 
WHERE c.parent_id = ? 
GROUP BY c.parent_id;
```

Can someone please specify a better way?

Comment: Could you post the results that you want?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. The required columns are specified in the query I used.

Comment: do you want to retrieve just parent_id,count(dept_id), and count(emp_id)?

Comment: `SELECT c.parent_id,COUNT(d.dept_id),COUNT(d.emp_id) FROM company c 
LEFT JOIN department d ON c.comp_id = d.comp_id 
GROUP BY c.parent_id`

Comment: This query returns the same value for both counts. 
For ex: expected column values - 1, 4, 24. But making use of above query returs - 1, 24, 24.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.parent_id,COUNT(d.dept_id),COUNT(DISTINCT(d.emp_id))
FROM company c LEFT JOIN department d ON c.comp_id = d.comp_id 
GROUP BY c.parent_id
```

Comment: This one uses DISTINCT. The whole purpose was to avoid it using some workaround.

Comment: Do you want to avoid all use `DISTINCT`? try `SELECT DISTINCT`.